# tmux: variable indicating whether text is selected?

Tags: key-bindings, tmux

I use vi keybindings in Tmux's copy-mode, and I'd like to make <kbd>Esc</kbd> clear the current selection if there is one, or exit copy-mode if nothing was selected.

```
bind -T copy-mode-vi Escape if-shell -F '#{selection_active_flag}' \
                                        'send-keys -X clear-selection' \
                                        'send-keys -X cancel'
```

I was hoping Tmux might expose a variable that indicates the selection state (I made up `selection_active_flag` to express my intent, it doesn't actually exist), similar to `window_zoomed_flag` (which does exist).

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tmux 2.6 introduced `selection_present`. As stated in the [changelog](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/blob/e58d16b2df52beefd5094ac61bb9e44c123df3e7/CHANGES#L52),

> - Add selection_present format when in copy mode (allows key bindings that do
>     something different if there is a selection).

This is exactly what I was looking for, and though I'm running Tmux 2.6, it seems I have an outdated man page, as it made no mention of `selection_present`.

The final working solution is:

```
bind -T copy-mode-vi Escape if-shell -F '#{selection_present}' \
                                        'send-keys -X clear-selection' \
                                        'send-keys -X cancel'
```